# How to disable IP access

Tags: apache-2.2

How can I prevent visitors from accessing my site by IP? For example, my website uses IP 1.2.3.4, when they access http://1.2.3.4 directly, I want to redirect them to www.mywebsite.com or show them an error message.

I'm using Apache 2.2. Thanks!

Comment: You can do such redirect to a domain name with mod_rewrite.

Comment: @lastsmoke can you post the link and we'll close this one as a duplicate? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

LazyOne pointed out that you can do this with [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (rewrite your IP to your domain name - there are lots of questions here that deal with writing rewrite rules).

I don't really see the value of doing this:  Everyone accesses your website by IP address (after a DNS lookup turns your name into an IP), so the only real difference is what shows up in the `Host:` header, and you'll eat an extra HTTP request when the browser follows the redirect which makes things marginally slower.
If you need specific values in the `Host:` header for some reason though the rewrite rule solution will work for you.

Comment: Also i need to say the people that there a bunch of third party services that deal and fix this kind of things with a lot of additional layers of security like CloudFlare

Answer (score 1):

Aside from reading here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html

You can always drop via tcpwrappers /etc/hosts.deny or iptables :P

Comment: I think you misread the question (or I did) -- it sounds like they want to prevent people from accessing a site hosted on 1.2.3.4 by doing http://1.2.3.4/ (forcing them to use http://mysite.com/ and rewriting http://1.2.3.4/ appropriately if it's used).

Comment: you're absolutely right!